# 4 figures side by side in ieee latex paper

Tags: minipage, wrapfigure, includegraphics

I would like to have 4 figures side by side and I am getting this instead in latex
[image]

I would like to have them all side by side instead of having 3 in the first row and the 4th figure in the second row.

Here is the code I am using:

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\usepackage{subfigure}   


\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure*}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.24\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4.95cm,height=4cm]{Figures/TracePrecisionVsTtoNError.png}
\caption{T trace Precision \% versus T$\rightarrow$N errors Seeding}
\label{TracePrecisionTError}
\end{minipage}\qquad
\begin{minipage}[b]{.24\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4.95cm,height=4cm]{Figures/TracePrecisionVsTtoNError.png}
\caption{N trace Precision \% versus T$\rightarrow$N errors Seeding}
\label{NoTracePrecisionTError}
\end{minipage}\qquad
\begin{minipage}[b]{.24\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4.95cm,height=4cm]{Figures/TracePrecisionVsTtoNError.png}
\caption{T trace Recall \% versus T$\rightarrow$N errors Seeding}
\label{TraceRecallTError}
\end{minipage}\qquad
\begin{minipage}[b]{.24\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4.95cm,height=4cm]{Figures/TracePrecisionVsTtoNError.png}
\caption{N trace Recall \% versus T$\rightarrow$N errors Seeding}
\label{NoTraceRecallTError}
\end{minipage}


\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

here is the picture I am using for each figure: TracePrecisionVsTtoNError.png
[image]

Comment: Replace \qquad with \hfill. It might also be better to set the width of the images relative to the available text width instead of using  absolute values. In order to make sure your images don't get distorted, just specify the width. The height is then  calculated automatically.

Comment: It would be better to use `subfig` than `minipage`, especially if the figures belong to same 'group'. Either way, you have to replace `\qquad` with `\hfill` or reduce the figure width.

Comment: Shrinking the plots so that they fit the available space is not necessarily a good approach as the fonts might become too small and then unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 4 minipages each 24% of `\textwidth`.  Herw the three occurrences of `\qquad` you use for spacing takes more than the remainging 4%.

Just replace all occurrences of `\qquad` by `\hfill` to spread the remaining 4% of spaces between the figures.